# Google map android api version 2 for Android 2.2 and upper monodroid

Tags: xamarin.android, google-maps-android-api-2, xamarin

I'm trying to use Google Map Andorid API version 2 for android 2.2 and upper.

I use MapsAndLocationDemo_v2 and change the items that listed in the [readme](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/MapsAndLocationDemo_v2#backwards-compatibility-with-gingerbread--froyo) for supporting android 2.2 and uppper but I ye have some errors.

In this line of code:

```
[FragmentActivity ( Label = "@string/activity_label_mapwithmarkers") ]
```

I got this error:

```
projectpath\MapsAndLocationDemo_v2\SimpleMapDemo\MapWithMarkersActivity.cs(3,3): Error CS0616: 'Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentActivity' is not an attribute class (CS0616) (SimpleMapDemo)
```

same error in this line:

```
[FragmentActivity ( Label = "@string/activity_label_samplemap") ]
```

I also tried to use both Android.App and Android.Support.V4.App . and Instead of FragmentActivity in the above code use Activity. Build errors not appear but I see error in run-time about not defined Activity in the Manifest.

**Edit**

When I use this code:

```
[Activity(Label = "@string/activity_label_mapwithmarkers")]
```

Application runs but when I tried to go in map page it force closed.

What is the problem?

Comment: I'm yet wondering , do any body have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no FragmentActivity attribute.  That still remains [Activity(Label = "TITLE")]. You do need to change all the activities so that the subclass FragmentActivity however.

Comment: But when I use [Activity(Label = "TITLE")] application forced close

Comment: This is probably due to some other error. If you go to [the Maps and Location Demo](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/MapsAndLocationDemo_v2) on github, I just updated it to include a sample API 8 (Android 2.2) project.